# Submitting Button Value to Controller but fail to post the value

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I know i have made mistakes here but i have been searching for this for the whole day.
I used yii2 framework and i am still new here, 
I want to access `partone/two` page, the `partone/two` page has two submit buttons, one is for adding row, the second one is for validating the input

inside **PartoneController.php**

```
<?
public function actionTwo() { 

    if(\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) { 
        $this->goHome();
    } 

    $models = []; 
    $val = "" ;
        //Create array of items 
    Yii::trace("Lets start: ");

    if(Yii::$app->request->post('addRow') == 'true'){
      Yii::trace("hello");
      Model::loadMultiple($models, Yii::$app->request->post('items'));

      $model = new RelationForm();
      array_push($models, $model);
      return $this->render('two', ['items' => $models]); 
    } 

    if (Model::loadMultiple($models, Yii::$app->request->post('items')) && Model::validateMultiple($models)) 
    { 
        Yii::trace("hello again");
        $count = 0; 
        for($i = 0 ; $i < $models.length(); $i++){ 
            if(strpos($relationShownCurrently, '' + $i) !== FALSE){ 
                if(!$items[$i]->store()){ 
                    return $this->render('two', [ 'items' => $models ]); 
                }; 
            } 
        } 

        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "Processed {$count} records successfully."); 
        return $this->redirect(['index']); // redirect to your next desired page 
    } else { 

        for($i = 0; $i < 5 ; $i++) { 
            $models[$i] = new RelationForm(); 
        } 
        return $this->render('two', ['items' => $models]); 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

inside **two.php**

```
<?php
use yii\app\clientScript;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\models\relation;

$this->registerJsFile('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js');

function addRelationForm($form, $item, $i){

    return '<div class="col-md-12" id=\'r_'.($i).'\'>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label> Friend ' . ($i + 1) . '</label>'.
            $form->field($item, "user_friend_id[$i]") .
            '<label> Closeness to you </label>
        <div class="form-inline">   ' .
            $form->field($item,  "[$i]closeness")->radio(array("label" => "1", "value" => 1)) .
             $form->field($item, "[$i]closeness")->radio(array("label" => "2", "value" => 2)) . 
             $form->field($item, "[$i]closeness")->radio(array("label" => "3", "value" => 3)) .
             $form->field($item, "[$i]closeness")->radio(array("label" => "4", "value" => 4)).
             $form->field($item, "[$i]closeness")->radio(array("label" => "5", "value" => 5)) .
            '</div>'
            .'<div class="form-inline" >
            I know this person as a friend for approximately (in year) '.
            $form->field($item, "[$i]known_for")->textInput(["type" => "number", "placeholder" => '(in year)'])->label(false).
            '</div>'.
    '</div></div>';
}?>

<h1>Friendship Survey</h1>

<p> Introverted the space below, list up to ten of your closest friends that are currently in Econs/ Math and Econs; a minimum of 5 is compulsory. *Please select their full names from the dropdown list provided. Also, please select on the scale how close you are to each friend. 1Note the incentives for this section </p>


<?php $form =ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'partone-two-form']) ?>
    <?php foreach ($items as $i => $item) { 
            echo addRelationForm($form ,$item, $i);
    }?>

<hr>
<div class="row">
    **<div style="float:left" class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Add row', ['name' => 'addMore', 'value' => 'true', 'class' => 'btn btn-info']) ?>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right" class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Next Page', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'button-value', 'value' => 'next']) ?>
  </div>**
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end()?>

<?php $this->registerJsFile('/advanced/frontend/web/js/partone-two.js');?>
```

**Problem Explanation:**

I want to determine which button is fired, i have specified the name and the value of the submitbutton (addRow button and nextPage button in **two.php**). But i could not get the value in **PartoneController.php** by using `Yii::$app->request->post('addRow') == 'true'`, but failed

Other Solutions I have tried:
I have tried to use normal html for the button, and i cannot use `$_POST` in controller yii, **the compler says**

**** This is my updated code based on ScaiEdge Feedback:****

```
    public function actionTwo(){ 
        if(\Yii::$app->user->isGuest){ 
            $this->goHome();
        } 

        $models = []; 
        $val = "" ;
        $submit = Yii::$app->request->post('command');


        for($i = 0; $i < 5 ; $i++){ 
                $models[$i] = new RelationForm(); 
        }
    //Create array of items 
        Yii::trace("command: "  .$submit);
        if($submit  == 'addmore'){
            Yii::trace( "hello");
            Model::loadMultiple($models, Yii::$app->request->post('items'));

            $model = new RelationForm();
            array_push($models, $model);
            return $this->render('two', ['items' => $models]); 

        }


        if (Model::loadMultiple($models, Yii::$app->request->post()) ) 
        { 


            Yii::trace("hello again");
            $count = 0; 
            for($i = 0 ; $i < count($models); $i++){ 
                if(!$models[$i]->validate()){
                    if($models[$i]->hasErrors()){
                        Yii::trace( Html::errorSummary($models[$i]  ));
                    }  

                    return $this->render('two', ['items' => $models]);     
                }
            }

            for($i = 0 ; $i < count($models); $i++){ 
                if(!$models[$i]->store()){
                     return $this->render('two', ['items' => $models]);     
                }
            }

            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "Processed {$count} records successfully."); 
            return $this->redirect('three', ['items' => $models]);// redirect to your next desired page 
        }
        else {  



            return $this->render('two', ['items' => $models, 'submit' => $submit ]); 
        } 
        return null; 
}
```

Html Client Side:

```
    <h1>Friendship Survey</h1>

    <p> Introverted the space below, list up to ten of your closest friends that are currently in Econs/ Math and Econs; a minimum of 5 is compulsory. *Please select their full names from the dropdown list provided. Also, please select on the scale how close you are to each friend. 1Note the incentives for this section </p>
    <?php $form =ActiveForm::begin() ?>
        <?php foreach ($items as $i => $item) { 
                echo addRelationForm($form ,$item, $i);
            } 
         ?>

        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div style="float:left" >
                <?= Html::submitButton('Add Row', [ 'name' => 'command', 'value'  =>  'addmore', 'class' => 'btn btn-info']) ?>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right" >
                <?= Html::submitButton('Next Page', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'command', 'value' =>  'nextpage']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end()?>
```

When i removed this in the client side, it works, can anyone explain why? 
     $item) { 
                echo addRelationForm($form ,$item, $i);
                } 
            ?>

the client side become like

```
    <?php $form =ActiveForm::begin() ?>

   <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div style="float:left" >
                <?= Html::submitButton('Add Row', [ 'name' => 'chosen', 'value'  =>  'addmore', 'class' => 'btn btn-info']) ?>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right" >
                <?= Html::submitButton('Next Page', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'chosen', 'value' =>  'nextpage']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end()?>
```

addRelationForm function:

```
  function addRelationForm($form, $item, $i){



        return '<div class="col-md-12" id=\'r_'.($i).'\'>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label> Friend ' . ($i + 1) . '</label>'.
         $form->field($item, "[$i]user_friend_id") .
       '<label> Closeness to you </label>

        <div class="form-inline">   ' .

            $form->field($item, "[$i]closeness")->widget(RangeInput::classname(), [
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Rate (1 - 5)...'],
                'html5Options' => [
                    'min' => 1, 'max' => 5,
                    'width' => '75%',
                    'addon' => ['append' => ['content' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>']]
                ]])->label(false).
        '</div> '.
        '<div class="form-inline" >
                I know this person as a friend for approximately (in year) '.
                $form->field($item, "[$i]known_for")->textInput(["type" => "number", "placeholder" => '(in year)'])->label(false).
        '</div></div></div>';

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two submit buttons,so the conflict occur in between two submit buttons.
Try changing Yii::$app->request->post('addRow') to Yii::$app->request->post('addmore')
for next page
try Yii::$app->request->post('nextpage')

Answer (score 0):

just do your submission with ajax and do whatever you want :

```
    $('.yourForm').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formdata = new FormData(this);
    var whatEverInAddition = $('SelectYourDesiredElements').val();
    formdata.append("whatEverInAddition", whatEverInAddition );
    $.ajax({
        url: ...
        and so on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of your two submit buttons can be obtained from \Yii::$app->request->post('command')